# Роль оператора using

Tags: c#, файлы

Вопрос по поводу оператора using.
Почему когда я пишу так, то в файл ничего не пишется.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
    string docPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "WriteLines.txt");
    StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath);
    outputFile.WriteLine(lines[0]);
}
```

А если по примеру с msdn делать, то всё работает. Какую роль играет оператор using в данном примере? Да и в общем объяснение "Предоставляет удобный синтаксис, обеспечивающий правильное использование объектов IDisposable" мне непонятно.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
    string docPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "WriteLines.txt");
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
            outputFile.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
        outputFile.WriteLine(line);
} // вызывает outputFile.Dispose(), который выталкивает на диск данные из буфера
```

Answer (score 4):

`using` автоматически `Dispose` и `Flush` вызывает.

Без `using` можно тоже самое написать:

```
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
string docPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "WriteLines.txt");
StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath);
outputFile.AutoFlush = true;

foreach (string line in lines)
    outputFile.WriteLine(line);

outputFile.Dispose();
```

Ну и в `try`/`finally` ещё заключить нужно.